# How to get content received by urllib2 with 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, urllib2, http-status-code-403

How can I get with urllib2 content of page sent with 403 Forbidden ?
In real browser I'm receiving customized 403 page, but urllib2 throws exception.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest you use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of urllib2 if possible, it will make your life better.

Anyway since you asked for urllib2 specifically, here's how:

```
try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com')
except urllib2.HTTPError as exc:
    if exc.code == 403:
        content = exc.read()
```

The `content` variable will hold the HTML source of the 403 page.